# Three.js pointLight seems not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

I am very new to WebGL and Three.js as well, so this might be very basic question and always somebody have asked before.

What I was playing with my codes was making the small solar system.

I used SpotLight with SpotLightHelper, and PointLight and PointLightHelper.
Geometries I've used are BoxGeometry and SphereGeometry. Though BoxGeometry seems to get a light from PointLight, SphereGeometry does not.

What do you think is the problem I made wrong?
Thank you for your time, in advance.

```
var width, height;
    var camera, renderer, scene;

    var position = {
        earth: {
            x: 200,
            y: 1,
            z: 0,
            theta: 0,
            traceRadius: 200
        }
    };

    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,        // Field of view
        400 / 400,  // Aspect ratio
        .1,         // Near
        10000       // Far);
    );
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
    scene.add(camera);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = false;

    var sunGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(70, 128, 128);
    var sunMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
    var sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeo, sunMat);
    sunMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    sunMesh.castShadow = true;
    sunMesh.receiveShadow = false;
    scene.add(sunMesh);

    var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
    var boxMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xfff0f0});
    var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, boxMat);
    boxMesh.position.set(-100, 100, 0);
    boxMesh.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(boxMesh);

    var earthTraceGeo = new THREE.CircleGeometry(position.earth.traceRadius, 128, 128);
    var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(earthTraceGeo);
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
    scene.add(line);

    var earthGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 128, 128);
    var earthMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
    var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeo, earthMat);
    earthMesh.position.set(position.earth.traceRadius, 0, 0);
    earthMesh.castShadow = true;
    earthMesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(earthMesh);

    var lightSize = 250;
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xff0000, 1000, lightSize, 2);
    pointLight.position.set(110, 0, 110);
    pointLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(pointLight);

    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1, 1000);
    spotLight.position.set(-200, 120, 200);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(spotLight);

    var spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( spotLight, 0xffbbaa);
    scene.add( spotLightHelper );

    var pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( pointLight, lightSize );
    scene.add( pointLightHelper );

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
//    scene.add(ambientLight);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    render();
    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    function render() {
//        spotLightHelper.update();

        position.earth.theta += 1;
        position.earth.x = getX(0, position.earth.theta, position.earth.traceRadius);
        position.earth.y = getY(0, position.earth.theta, position.earth.traceRadius);
        earthMesh.position.set(position.earth.x, position.earth.y, 0);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }

    function getX(x, theta, radius) {
        return x + Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * theta) * radius;
    }

    function getY(y, theta, radius) {
        return y + Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * theta) * radius;
    }
```

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/ne7gjdnq/623/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light of the point light source can't bee seen, because the color of the light is red `0xff0000` and the color of the sphere geometry is green `0x00ff00`.
The red light of the light source does not affect the green sphere. The box is affected, because its color is `0xfff0f0`.

Note, in the light model the colors are more or less multiplied. If one side of the multiplication of a color channel is 0, then the result is 0, too.

Either change the color of the light source

```
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff00, 1000, lightSize, 2);
```

or the color of the sphere

```
var sunGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(70, 128, 128);
var sunMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
var sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeo, sunMat);
```

to solve the issue.

See the result in the Example:

```js
var width, height;
var camera, renderer, scene;

var position = {
    earth: {
        x: 200,
        y: 1,
        z: 0,
        theta: 0,
        traceRadius: 200
    }
};

width = window.innerWidth;
height = window.innerHeight;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
//    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 1000);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,        // Field of view
    400 / 400,  // Aspect ratio
    .1,         // Near
    10000       // Far);
);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
scene.add(camera);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = false;

var sunGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(70, 128, 128);
var sunMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sunGeo, sunMat);
sunMesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
sunMesh.castShadow = true;
sunMesh.receiveShadow = false;
scene.add(sunMesh);

var boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50);
var boxMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xfff0f0});
var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, boxMat);
boxMesh.position.set(-100, 100, 0);
boxMesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(boxMesh);

var earthTraceGeo = new THREE.CircleGeometry(position.earth.traceRadius, 128, 128);
var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(earthTraceGeo);
var line = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
scene.add(line);

var earthGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(30, 128, 128);
var earthMat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});
var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeo, earthMat);
earthMesh.position.set(position.earth.traceRadius, 0, 0);
earthMesh.castShadow = true;
earthMesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(earthMesh);

var lightSize = 250;
var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff00, 1000, lightSize, 2);
pointLight.position.set(110, 0, 110);
pointLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(pointLight);

var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1, 1000);
spotLight.position.set(-200, 120, 200);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotLight);

var spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( spotLight, 0xffbbaa);
//    scene.add( spotLightHelper );

var pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( pointLight, lightSize );
scene.add( pointLightHelper );

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
//    scene.add(ambientLight);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

window.onresize = resize;

render();
document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function render() {
//        spotLightHelper.update();

    position.earth.theta += 1;
    position.earth.x = getX(0, position.earth.theta, position.earth.traceRadius);
    position.earth.y = getY(0, position.earth.theta, position.earth.traceRadius);
    earthMesh.position.set(position.earth.x, position.earth.y, 0);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function getX(x, theta, radius) {
    return x + Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * theta) * radius;
}

function getY(y, theta, radius) {
    return y + Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * theta) * radius;
}

function resize() {

var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.aspect = aspect;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
//controls.handleResize();
}
```

```css
* { padding:0; margin:0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="WebGL-output"></div>
```

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. What would you think is the right light I should use to make the solar system as a practice? I want the center circle, representing the sun as the only light, to light all the planets around it